# MS Word 2010 turns my text into squares

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am updating a file that I have created long time ago using Microsoft Word 2010, I enabled "Track Changes" did some changes, saved the document. When I opened it later I found all the text which I have added below equations had turned into squares like in the image below:

[image: text turned into squares]

The style of that text is based on "Normal" style, while the equations use a different style.

Changing the style of that text to the equation style changes the squares into Greek letters that are similar to the original text:
[image: greek text]

The original text is:

```
Yes it will work
No no no
Aaaaaaa
Bbbbbbb
```

(i don't remember the rest as i wrote some stuff just to test it)

I tried to create a new user profile in case it was a bug in the user's settings but that didn't help. MS Office 2010 is up to date.

The only solution I found is to disable Track Changes, that will not fix the already missed up text but it will stop it from happening to new entered text. But I need it enabled since I work on the file with other people.

Any help or suggestion?